# Avoid infered response type in generated swagger.json with TSOA (Express)

Tags: express, swagger, tsoa

I'm using **TSOA** to auto-generate a `swagger.json` file which will be rendered with `swagger-ui-express`

The problem is that, although the endpoint really returns a status code 200 and a response object, TSOA is interpreting that the `execute()` method does not return anything (`void`) and ends up indicating that in addition to returning a 200, it can also return a 204-NoContent

Is there a way to specify TSOA or Swagger to ignore this response possibility?

The Controller:

```
@Controller()
@Route('/user')
@Tags('User')
export class UserGetController extends BaseController<UserGetResponse> {

  @Get()
  @Response<UserGetResponse>(200)
  public async execute(): Promise<void> {
    this.sendResponse(UserGetController.toResponse({user: undefined}));
  }
}

  protected sendResponse(params: Record<string, unknown>, statusCode?: number): void {
    this.response.status(statusCode || 200).json(params);
  }
```

The generated code in `swagger.json` file:

```json
    "paths": {
        "/user": {
            "get": {
                "operationId": "Execute",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/UserGetResponse"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "204": {
                        "description": "No content"
                    }
                },
                "tags": [
                    "User"
                ],
                "security": [],
                "parameters": []
            }
        }
    },
```